# SSJS HTTP.Post ValidEmail with requested Access Token

Tags: marketing-cloud, ssjs, httppost, cloudpagesurl, email-validation

I am trying to make an API request in SFMC to validate email addresses, which requires first to get the Access Token.

I was able to request the access token, but then the next HTTP.Post request I do doesn't work. I have this far:

```
Platform.Load("core","1.1.5");


var dataRows = Platform.Function.LookupRows('NameofEmailsDE','ColumnName2Check','ValueName');
 if(dataRows && dataRows.length > 0) {
      for(var i=0; i<dataRows.length; i++) {

        var EmailAddress = dataRows[i]["ColumnNameToRetrieve"];

try {
        var authEndpoint = "https://uniqueclienturlapi.auth.marketingcloudapis.com";
        var client_id = "XXXXXXXXXXX";
        var client_secret = "XXXXXXXXXXX";
        var account_id = "XXXXXXXXX";
        var grant_type = "client_credentials";

        // auth        
        var url = authEndpoint + '/v2/token';
        var contentType = 'application/json';
        var payload = '{"grant_type":"' + grant_type + '",';
        payload += '"client_id":"' + client_id + '",';
        payload += '"client_secret":"' + client_secret + '"}';

        // create token
        var accessTokenResult = HTTP.Post(url, contentType, payload);
        var statusCode = result["StatusCode"];
        var response = accessTokenResult["Response"][0];
        var access_token = Platform.Function.ParseJSON(response).access_token; 



 /* Until here, the request works, and I get the access_token. The issue comes in this next request when I have to add to the HTTP.Post the headerNames + headerValues */



        var restEndpoint = "https://uniqueclienturlapi.rest.marketingcloudapis.com";
        restEndpoint += "/address/v1/validateEmail";  
        var headerNames = ["Authorization"];
        var headerValues = ["Bearer " + access_token]; 

        // payload
          var restpayload = '{';
          restpayload += ' "email": "' + EmailAddress + '",'; 
          restpayload += ' "validators": [ "SyntaxValidator", "MXValidator", "ListDetectiveValidator" ]';
          restpayload += '}';                            

        try {
            var restresult = HTTP.Post(restEndpoint, contentType, restpayload, headerNames, headerValues);
            var reststatusCode = result["StatusCode"];
            var response = restresult["Response"][0];
            var emailresponse = Platform.Function.ParseJSON(response).email;
            var validresponse = Platform.Function.ParseJSON(response).valid;
            var failedValidationresponse = Platform.Function.ParseJSON(response).failedValidation;
            }
        catch (err)  {
            // error
            //Write("error");
            }             
    }           

  catch (err)  {
    // error
    //Write("error");
    } 
  }     
}
```

---

I would appreciate any help! Thanks a lot

Comment: Can you give more info on how it does not work? Does it error? Not produce expected results? etc?

Comment: Agreed that you should share the output of your error so we can better help. Also, you should move your request for the access token outside of the for loop. Right now you are requesting a new access token for each iteration of the loop when a single request would be sufficient.

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't have any more information regarding the error message since I am running this script first in a Cloud Page. In the Automation Studio, there's also no info when the automation fails. That's why I decided to try in the CloudPages first. .

Can you help me to put the accestoken request outside the loop?

Comment: If you uncomment your `//Write("error")` and change it to `Write(Stringify(err))` you should be able to get an output on the CloudPage of what the issue is. To move the auth token call outside the loop, just move that above the for loop and remove the try/catch that is around it inside the loop.

Comment: Hi Gortonington,

thanks for your explanation. I moved the auth token call above the "for".
I got following error-message: 
"{"message":"Unable to retrieve security descriptor for this frame.","description":"System.InvalidOperationException: Unable to retrieve security descriptor for this frame. - from mscorlib\r\n\r\n"}{"message":"Unable to retrieve security descriptor for this frame.","description":"System.InvalidOperationException: Unable to retrieve security descriptor for this frame. - from mscorlib\r\n\r\n"}"

But I didn't remove the first try-catch that nests the second call

Comment: The problem I am having is inserting the given accessToken into the Header in the second call. Something is wrong. Because the variables restEndpoint, contentType and restpayload are shown. But then the response isn't = restresult, emailresponse, validresponse and failedValidationresponse

Comment: Is the Auth token call in its own try/catch? If so, you will need to return the auth token output to utilize it outside of it. Try/Catch is very similar to a function in that everything set or edited inside of it is kept internally only unless returned.

Comment: I tried it the way you showed above and it worked fine for me, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

for those who are waiting/looking for an answer on this topic this is how I implemented after many tries.

So this can actually work for any SSJS API call which requires the accessToken to proceed.

**STEPS:**

1) I created a first DataExt called 'ClientId_and_Secret_RequestToken' with 3 columns: TokenVersion, clientId, clientSecret and stored my credentials (this avoids anyone to inspect the page and take you clientId/clientSecret)

2) Second DataExt which contains the Email Addresses to validate (Columns: EmailAddress & toCheck)

3) Check the comments in the code

````
<script runat="server">
   Platform.Load("Core", "1.1.1");

   var TokenVersion = 2;
   // Initiate the first DataExt
   var credentialsDE = DataExtension.Init('ClientId_and_Secret_RequestToken');

   // Lookup for the right credentials
   var lookup = credentialsDE.Rows.Lookup(["TokenVersion"],[TokenVersion]);

        if (lookup.length > 0 ) {
            for (var i = 0; lookup.length > i; i++){
                //Set each variable
                var clientId = lookup[i]["clientId"];
                var clientSecret = lookup[i]["clientSecret"];
            }
        }

    var EmailValidationOutput = DataExtension.Init("EmailAddress2Check");

    //Lookup EmailAddresses in the second DataExt and loop what's next
    var dataRows = Platform.Function.LookupRows('EmailAddress2Check','toCheck','True');
        for(var i=0; i<dataRows.length; i++) {

            var EmailAddress = dataRows[i]["EmailAddress"];
            Variable.SetValue("EmailAddress",EmailAddress);
                try {
                  //API to requestToken
                    var url = 'https://{{UniqueClientURLapi}}.auth.marketingcloudapis.com/v2/token';
                    var contentType = 'application/json';
                    var payload = '{"grant_type": "client_credentials", "client_id": "' + clientId + '","client_secret": "' + clientSecret + '"}';
                    var accessTokenResult = HTTP.Post(url, contentType, payload); // HTTP POST call with parameters

                    var obj = Platform.Function.ParseJSON(accessTokenResult.Response + ''); // Parsing the JSON Response to get the token
                    var statusCode = accessTokenResult["StatusCode"];
                    var response = accessTokenResult["Response"][0];
             var accessToken = Platform.Function.ParseJSON(response).access_token;
                    var BearerT = 'Bearer ' + accessToken;

                    if (statusCode === 200) {
                        // Another API call here or something else     
                        var jbHeaderNames = ["Authorization"];
                        var jbHeaderValues = [BearerT];
                        var jbContentType = 'application/json';

               //Here can be changed for any API request

                        var restEndpoint = "https://{{UniqueClientURLapi}}.rest.marketingcloudapis.com/address/v1/validateEmail";
                        var jbPayload = '{"email": "' + EmailAddress + '" , "validators": [ "SyntaxValidator", "MXValidator", "ListDetectiveValidator" ]}';    
                        var validationResult = HTTP.Post(restEndpoint, jbContentType, jbPayload, jbHeaderNames, jbHeaderValues);
                        var validation = validationResult["Response"][0];
                        var emailResponse = Platform.Function.ParseJSON(validation).email;
                        var valid = Platform.Function.ParseJSON(validation).valid;
                        var failedValidation = Platform.Function.ParseJSON(validation).failedValidation;


                    // Debug info below
                    Write('<br>'+emailResponse + '<br>');
                    Write(valid + '<br>' + '<br>');
                    Write(failedValidation + '<br>');

                    } else {
                        // block of code to be executed if the condition1 is false
                    }
                } catch (ex) {
                    Write("error message: " + ex);
                }
        }    
</script> ```
````